# Android interface - need suggestions on what widgets to use

Tags: android

I need to create interface that will look like "order". So, there will be header data and then there will be details. I see it as all scrollable screen. But I'm not sure what the best way to bind details.

I can see how I can:

1. Create ListView and put header in first row - IMO UGLY code.
2. Create ListActivity, put header on top and ListView below - no good either since header won't scroll.
3. I'm not sure HOW to do it but idea is to create main layout and put empty LinearLayout where details should be. Then create another Layout for details (just like I do for ListView). But I would load details and inflate those childs manually and then inject them into my LinearLayout.

Will that work? How else would you do something like that?

Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest using the ListView to display minimal information and then display a details activity on tap.

Comment: @Matt - This is trip information. On top - info like miles, dates, etc will be displayed. Each detail will be a "STOP". will be at least 2 (pickup and delivery) but there can be more in a middle (drops or pickups).

Comment: @dmon I already have ListView that displays list of "orders" with summary info. When user clicks it - I display this detail screen so I don't want to popup anything. Just scrolling. Otherwise it will be to "deep"

Comment: I thought I understood but probably not. You want to inflate the details inside the same listview? Put the details below each item and show only after clicking on that item?

Comment: @Aleadam That is to get fancy - I can expand detail when click on it. But this is now what I want to accomplish now. I want WHOLE screen to be scrollable.

Comment: @katit then you have two options: the *ugly* code you mention as the option 1 or a set of `LinearLayout`/`RelativeLayout`s inside a `ScrollView`

Comment: Can I create my own "custom control" ? And then manually inflate it and populate details like that? This way I can put it all in a scrollview without adapters and ListView

Comment: @katit Indeed. You can populate everything at once and play with the visibility of each view. I'll add a very basic example to my answer.

Comment: @katit I added an example of what I meant.

Comment: @Aleadam Great! That will make it even more pretty. It comes together nicely now I wish I can inflate control from XML. Do you know how to do that? I created another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901565/inflating-layout-in-custom-control-how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to add both a `TextView` and a `ListView` inside a `RelativeLayout`. You can actually replace the `Textivew` with any `View` (including a `ViewGorup`) you need.

See how to implement it in this tutorial: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html

and check also Romain Guy's posts for a nice comparison between `LinearLayout` and `RelativeLayout` (and good advise in general):

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-1.html

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-2-reusing-layouts.html

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-with.html

---

### Update

This is a (very simplified) way to create an expandable `LinearLayout`. Of course, instead of buttons, you will add some more interesting content...

- **File `MyCustomControl.java`**

.

```
package com.aleadam.test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyCustomControl extends LinearLayout {
    Context context;
    Button upper, lower;
    TextView tv;

    public MyCustomControl(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        expandLayout();
    }

    public MyCustomControl(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
        expandLayout();
    }

    private void expandLayout() {
        setOrientation (VERTICAL);
        LayoutParams lp0 = new LayoutParams(
                 LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        LayoutParams lp1 = new LayoutParams(
                 LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 40);
        LayoutParams lp2 = new LayoutParams(
                 LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 200);
        TextView tv = new TextView(context);
        tv.setText("The title goes here");

        upper = new Button(context);
        upper.setText("Click to show the other button");

        lower = new Button(context);
        lower.setText("Click to hide this button");
        lower.setVisibility(GONE);

        upper.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener () {
            public void onClick (View v) {
                lower.setVisibility(VISIBLE);               
            }
        });
        lower.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener () {
            public void onClick (View v) {
                v.setVisibility(GONE);              
            }
        });      

        this.addView(tv, lp0);
        this.addView(upper, lp1);
        this.addView(lower, lp2);
    }
}
```

- **File `Test.java`**

.

```
public class Test extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        inflateLayout();
    }
    public void inflateLayout() {
        ScrollView scr = new ScrollView (this);
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout (this);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        ll.addView (new MyCustomControl (this));
        ll.addView (new MyCustomControl (this));
        ll.addView (new MyCustomControl (this));
        ll.addView (new MyCustomControl (this));
        scr.addView(ll);
        setContentView (scr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a header to a ListView using the addHeader method providing a custom view that you can inflate from another XML: [ListView addHeader method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean%29)

Comment: But will it be scrollable? I thought header will stay on top of the screen

Comment: It will stay on top of the list but not on top of the screen. It will act like if it was the first row of the `ListView`

Answer (score 0):

```
LinearLayout _> ScrollView _> LinearLayout _/- TextView header
                                            \- ListView w/ adapter
```