# Inflating layout in custom control - how?

Tags: android, android-layout

I've got and idea on how to create custom control here:
[Android interface - need suggestions on what widgets to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891153/android-interface-need-suggestions-on-what-widgets-to-use)

How do I make the SAME but creating control's layout in XML and just inflating it in code? Not like in this example where I have to create each control manually.

My first problem that LinearLayout that used as a base does not support setView() command. Should I extend something else?

EDIT: I found 
This:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html
and this:
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List4.html

Seems like I need COMPOUND CONTROL. I just need little bit of code. How do I inflate control's content from XML? BOth article and sample say I can but HOW?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have to use a layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <View android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="0px"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:background="#0F0"/>
  <View android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="0px"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:background="#0FF"/>
</merge>
```

where `<merge>` means "put everything that's inside me into the parent I'm going to be inflated to".

Then in code:

```
public class CControl extends LinearLayout {

    public CControl(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CControl(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        inflater.inflate(R.layout.tryout, this);
    }
    // ......
}
```

At this point you can use your compound control as if it's a LinearLayout, so you'll have to specify in the outer layout if you want it to be vertical, for example, or you could set it as a default inside the constructor.

Comment: That's event better. What if I don't want LinearLayout to be base? SHould I extend View? I'm looking for the lightest possible container for my compound control. I will insert it into Activity with LinearLayout anyway, so I don't need another nest level.

Comment: @katit: I'd extend View if I'm creating a whole new view, drawing everything in onDraw(). You need a layout for a compound control, because it must be a reusable unity somehow, and the choice depends mostly on how you want to layout the children views. I wouldn't worry too much about optimization, unless you're displaying hundreds of these (which would be bad anyway).

Comment: Got it. I won't display hungreds. Usually 2-3 maybe 4. I like to learn best way from beginning. But here it seems like using layout will be OK.